# Javascript OnBlur not working

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, radio-button, onblur

I have a textbox which is disabled by default... the onclick works and enables it to be typed in, but when i click the radio button away.. it doesn't disable the textbox again

Any clues ?

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="website" OnBlur="javascript:document.getElementById('websiteurl').disabled = true;" OnClick="javascript:document.getElementById('websiteurl').disabled = false;">
<input name="websiteurl" type="text" id="websiteurl" value="http://" size="50" disabled="true" />
```

Thanks in advance

Lee

Comment: When you mean click the radio button away do you mean click another radio button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no attribute `enabled`. You use `disabled` and set it to `true` or `false`.

Besides that:

Use lowercase attributes (otherwise it's not valid XHTML); there's no need to put `javascript:` in front of it.
Additionally, it is better to attach events from JavaScript code instead of inlining them. Especially if you use a library like jQuery it's extremely easy:

```
$('input[name=group1][value=website]').blur(function() {
    $('#websiteurl').attr('disabled', 'true');
}).click(function() {
    $('#websiteurl').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

(of course a `#id` would be much better instead of the `input[name=group1][value=website]` selector)

Answer (score 2):

There is no attribute "enabled". You would have to set disabled to "disabled" to disable an input, or remove the attribute "disabled" to enable it.

disabled="true" is the wrong syntax, it should be disabled="disabled"

Answer (score 0):

Try `disabled=true` instead of `enabled=false`

Comment: Yes sorry that was the incorrect code i tried to get it working... it is disabled=true and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Change enabled to disabled and it will work.

There is no enabled property.

Comment: Yes sorry that was the incorrect code i tried to get it working... it is disabled=true and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure on the context, but wouldn't a checkbox be more appropriate in this situation to disable or enable a textbox?

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#websiteurl').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#websiteurl').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```